# Angular 4 Typescript http post request not working

Tags: php, angular, typescript, http-post

I'm trying to make a working contact form for my class project by making an http post request to a php file on the server. I know the php file works because when I route to it directly it pings my email, and when I debug in the browser I can see that it's trying to build the http request. The problem I'm having is that I don't really understand what I'm doing.. I'm hoping someone can tell me what's wrong with my code or point me in the right direction. Any help would be greatly appreciated... Here's what I have so far:

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
}

data = {
    name:'name',
    phone:'555-5555',
    email:'email@gmail.com',
    message:'hello'
}

constructor(private http: Http) { }

postData() {
    console.log(this.data);
    this.http.post('http://mywebsite.net/contact_me.php', 
this.data, this.headers);
}
```

Comment: Does your server script supports CORS requests? In other words, is CORS enabled?

Comment: Subscribe to it and please post the console.log in  success, failure and complete functions

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really know how to log those functions. when I logged the result I got the following error: 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mywebsite.net/contact_me.php. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 1):

i have also face this problem

> step1 set Headers in php file

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

sample function where you can Get Response

```
   public function createAction(Request $request) {

    $data=file_get_contents('php://input');

    var_dump($data);//here you print you 'POST' or 'GET' Response.
```

> step2 service.ts formService.ts

```
 private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'});

 private insertdataUrl = 'api-url';

 //create function that is called by component.html file
  create(user: ApiDashboard) {
   return this.http.post(this.insertdataUrl,user).map(response => response.json());

   }
  //here in my code ApiDashboard is model
```

> step3 define you service function in component.ts file

```
export class ApiDashboardformComponent implements OnInit {
model: any = {};
 loading = false;
  constructor(private router: Router,
    private formService: FormService
    ) { }

 ngOnInit() {
 }
Create() {
    this.loading = true;
        this.formService.create(this.model)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.formService.success('Registration successful', true);
                this.router.navigate(['/material-dashboard']);
            },
            error => {
                this.formService.error(error);
                this.loading = false;
            });
      }
     }
```

> step4 finally call create() function component.html file

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <h2>Register</h2>
  <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && Create()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added this to my php file:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
```

and updated my body parameter to:

```
JSON.stringify(this.data)
```

I'm still having issues with my headers param coming back as 'undefined' but this was enough to at least ping my email with an empty message. Thanks for the help!